# Rails.ajax call returning false (rails-ujs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-ujs

I'm trying using ajax with [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) but my call doesn't doing nothing. The application use the rails 5.1 and have the rails-ujs require in application.js

When i test the code in a browser console, it is return false.

Bellow is the code:

```
  Rails.ajax({
    url: "/notifications.json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Did you wrap this appropriately for Turbolinks?

Comment: I'm not using turbolinks

Comment: Turbolinks is irrelevant seeing as OP mentioned they're testing in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To makes the ajax call work with rails-ujs(without jQuery) i don't found
any documentation at moment and hope this code bellow helpes.

```
Rails.ajax({
  dataType: 'script',
  url: "/notifications.json",
  type: "GET",
  beforeSend: function() {
    return true
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Ajax fine!')
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a bug with rails_ujs. But thanks for the answer!